# PHP capturar arreglo bidimencional

Tags: php, html, array

He estado tratando de solucionar un tema, pero no he encontrado con la respuesta...

Este trozo de código me termina de generar una matriz de AxB desde datos recuperados de una base de datos.

```
<?php for ($i=1;$i<=$cantidad_notas;$i++){                      
          $na = mysqli_fetch_row($notas3);?>
          <td>
              <input type="hidden" name="id_alumno[][]" value="<?php echo $ver[0] ?>"/>
              <input type="hidden" name="id_nota[][]" size="1" value="<?php if($na[0]!=0){echo $na[0];}else{echo '""';} ?>"/>
              <input type="number" class="form-control-sm" name="nota[][]" size="1" value="<?php echo $na[4]; ?>" min="10" max="70"/>
          </td>
<?php } ?>
```

El tema es que no se como recorrerlo al momento de recibirlo para realizar las modificaciones, ya que solo logro recorrer la primera fila de la matriz con este código:

```
$nota = $_POST['nota'];
for($j=0;$j<$cantidadAlumnos;$j++){
    for($i=0;$i<$cantidadNotas;$i++){
        echo $nota[$i][$j];
    }
}
```

y obviamente así con las otras variables...

Comment: No queda clara la pregunta, porqué no no pones mejor un ejemplo del array que tienes y como deseas recorrerlo. Intenta aclara mas tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte. Puedes darle una vuelta al [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) también para conocer el sitio y obtener tu primera medalla. Bienvenido a SOes.

Answer (score 0):

$consulta = "SELECT nombre, apellido FROM Persona";

if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {

```
/* obtener el array de objetos */
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_row()) {?>
    <td>Agregas lo que necesitas de tu resultado....</td>
<?}

/* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
$resultado->close();
```

}
Esto te va a regresar los valores que hay en cada campo.